# Flickering AVPlayerController Edge (iOS)

Tags: ios, avplayer, avplayerviewcontroller

I have an AVPlayerController and have shifted it up 100px. The background of the video is solid white and the background in the app is solid white. Yet there's a weird flickering on the edge when it scrolls.

You can see the border right above the signup button and at the edge of the cell. I even tried putting a second view above it with a white stroke to hide it, and it just shifted it in more. The fact it's not a single color and instead flickers is super strange to me.

Any ideas how to fix it?

Video -
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1kBK92teYIm29_tAMFpMizdAMAVw8CknV/view?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

As a quick solution, you can make screenshot of the video and put it on overlay view of the AVPlayerViewController while scrolling.

**Edited:** You can try to set overlay property as UIView with white background color and see if the gap is gone. It may looks like that:

```
UIView *overlay = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:self.myPlayerVC.bounds];
overlay.backgroundColor = [UIColor whiteColor];
self.myPlayerVC.contentOverlayView = overlay;
```

Comment: How would you go about implementing that?